# how to separate character in images after filling holes?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to fill holes in character from captcha images using python and opencv. I am able to remove line and remove small dots from captcha. but after removing line and small dots from character, there  are cut at different place where intersection of line and character meet. i am able to apply erosion and dilution but character are not separated properly. Any help appreciated.[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfG3x.png) can be found here.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread('captcha.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for i,row in enumerate(gray):
    for j,col in enumerate(row):
        if gray[i][j] >= 110:
            gray[i][j] = 255
        else:
            gray[i][j] = 0
cv2.imshow("Background Removal", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# need to fill cut character

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=2)
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
gray = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow('After Separation', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business

Comment: we are working on public data only.

Comment: But what are you going to do with your code once you get it working?